# How to delete a monthly partition from VictoriaMetrics vmstore nodes

Tags: victoriametrics

We are backfilling old data into our VictoriaMetrics and Grafana setup. But we might have messed up the data on a month. We want to delete a monthly partition from vmstore nodes and start again. Is this possible through the APIs?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can do this via [VictoriaMetrics Delete API](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-delete-time-series) `/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series`. Note, that you can only delete **All of the data** and restore/backfill ones again.

See examples below:

**Single-node VictoriaMetrics**

`curl -v http://localhost:8428/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series -d 'match[]=your_metric_name_here'`

**Cluster version of VictoriaMetrics**

`curl -v http://<vmselect>:8481/delete/0/prometheus/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series -d 'match[]=your_metric_name_here'`

VictoriaMetrics documentation has a [guide](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/guides/guide-delete-or-replace-metrics.html) "**How to delete or replace metrics in VictoriaMetrics**" with more explanation and examples.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and the fastest way to remove a month-worth partition of data in VictoriaMetrics is to stop VictoriaMetrics (or a vmstorage in cluster version), then delete the `YYYY_MM` directory for the needed month under the `<-storageDataPath>/data/{small,big}` directories and then start VictoriaMetrics again. See more details about storage in VictoriaMetrics in [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#storage).